# Is reasking questions allowed under any conditions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

Suppose i added a question which i expected to get a lot of attention and plenty of answers, but the question ends up with very little views. Afterwards, i realise that's probably because i chose a very bad title. I could edit it, but at this point it's far down the list and it's going to be seen only by a few people. Would you see a repost with more communicative title as acceptable?

If not, when would you consider reasking as mandated?

Answer (score 3):

If you edit the question it will go to the top of the main page because it sorts by activity by default. This should give it added attention. You're also welcome to swing by the chat room to discuss the topic and see if anyone would like to weigh in.

If you really feel that all hope is lost, and the question was badly received, it may be possible for you to delete it and then ask it again.

Answer (score 1):

To add to fooot's reply, the "bounty" system of Stack Exchange is designed for this scenario. You offer an amount of your rep points as exchange for someone answering your question.

The steps are:

1. Edit the question first. An edit puts the question back to the top of the page.
2. Wait awhile. Aviation.SE is not as active (e.g. compared to StackOverflow). From my experience 3~5 days should be enough to get some of the experts on the site to at least view your question. If your question asks for more generic or basic topics, you will typically get a very good response within 24 hours.
3. If there is a lack of interest, you may wish to add more details / links / images etc. (without making the question too broad or too long). This goes back to step #1.
4. If nothing else works, [offer a bounty](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). I've done it a few times and it worked for me.